# What is a good way to visualize common string values from multiple dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have multiple dataframes(one for each city) with 'Name' column that represents organization names from that city.

How can I visualize the names that are common in every 2 cities and the names that are common for all cities so that it would be easy to understand?

Example:

```py
  df1            df2

  Name           Name       
'Apollo'        'Kims'
'MedWorks'      'AIMs'
'Cradle'        'Apollo'
'Kims'          'Bronte Co'
'Collins'       'Cradle'
```

There are more than 10 values(names) common for each city. I am not sure if venn diagrams work with string values but even if they do, it will not fit all the data in a good format.

Tried [this as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717203/plot-actual-set-items-in-python-not-the-number-of-items) but I am getting:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plot actual set items in python, not the number of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717203/plot-actual-set-items-in-python-not-the-number-of-items)

Comment: I don't think this approach works for string values.

Comment: I am getting: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`matplotlib_venn`](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn):

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib_venn import venn2

set1 = set(df1['Name'])
set2 = set(df2['Name'])

venn = venn2([set1, set2])
venn.get_label_by_id('100').set_text('\n'.join(map(str,set1-set2)))
venn.get_label_by_id('110').set_text('\n'.join(map(str,set1&set2)))
venn.get_label_by_id('010').set_text('\n'.join(map(str,set2-set1)))
# venn.get_label is quoted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717203/plot-actual-set-items-in-python-not-the-number-of-items
```

Output:

[image]